# How to get a data element in pandas that is not in the index (but between those values)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series of discrete states a system can be set to. The setting is done at discrete time steps, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
states = pd.Series([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], index=pd.date_range(
'2015-01-01', freq='2Min', periods=8))
```

This results in:

```
2015-01-01 00:00:00    1
2015-01-01 00:02:00    1
2015-01-01 00:04:00    0
2015-01-01 00:06:00    0
2015-01-01 00:08:00    1
2015-01-01 00:10:00    0
2015-01-01 00:12:00    1
2015-01-01 00:14:00    0
Freq: 2T, dtype: int64
```

This means the system is in state 1  in the first four minutes, starting from minute 5 in state 0 and so on. Now it is necessary to answer in which state the system is at 3 minutes and 34 seconds. Quite obvious `states['2015-01-01 00:03:45']` won't work but raise a key error.

Is there an elegant solution to do so? I assume I could do

```
index = np.where(states.index < '2015-01-01 00:03:45')[-1][-1]
state = states.iloc[index]
```

to get these data but I consider this as rather ugly and I'd be happy for any suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your Series has a DatetimeIndex, you could use [the `asof` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.asof.html):

```
In [11]: states.asof('2015-01-01 00:03:45')
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: states.asof('2015-01-01 00:04:00')
Out[15]: 0
```